Package error while flutter build app --release
When I run and debug my application via Flutter vs code, there is no problem, but when I print the apk in release mode, the packages in the pubsbec.yaml file are not installed.
dependencies: cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6 flutter: sdk: flutter google_fonts: ^6.2.1 http: ^1.2.1 shared_preferences: ^2.2.3 flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2 These are the packages I use.
Normally, the fonts of the texts should be changed, but the text does not change because google_fonts is not loaded.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

remove versions of issued packages and then run
 flutter clean 
 flutter pub get

